# Azure Data Factory: Which Version of npgsql is used?

Tags: postgresql, azure, azure-data-factory, npgsql

As far as I understand, the Azure Datafactory V2 uses the .NET framework "npgsql" to copy data from or to a PostgreSQL database.
Currently, I am having issues with some data types in the PostgreSQL database I want to copy data from. With the newer versions of npgsql, it should be possible to read these data types. Hence the question:
What version of npgsql does the Azure Data Factory V2 use?
Is it possible to check the version of npgsql?

I don't know if this helps, but I am using a Self Hosted Runtime Environment version 5.1.7655.1

Comment: According to this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/data-factory/v1/data-factory-onprem-postgresql-connector#supported-versions-and-installation). The version may be between 2.0.12 and 3.1.9.

Comment: The documentation is about Version 1 of the Data Factory, if I siwtch the docs to V2, there is no information of the version. Thanks for the comment! I specified the Version of the Data Factory in the question

Comment: @MikeS you are using self-hosted integration runtime to copy the data from local PostgreSQL. Can you show us what's the error or any screenshot that you can't read the data type? We need more details about the question, not only to know the ngpsql version.

Comment: In this [ADF V2 documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-postgresql) it says : `The Integration Runtime provides a built-in PostgreSQL driver starting from version 3.7, therefore you don't need to manually install any driver.`

Comment: @LeonYue error message is exactly as stated here: https://github.com/npgsql/npgsql/issues/2005 . But that would be another question. Anyways, I think I got the answer to my original question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can conclude that:

1. According to the [ADF V1 documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/data-factory/v1/data-factory-onprem-postgresql-connector#supported-versions-and-installation), the built-in driver version is between 2.0.12 and 3.1.9.
2. According to the [ADF V2 documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/data-factory/connector-postgresql), the driver starting from version 3.7. It seems that we cannot manually specify the version number.
   Kindly let me know if you need more information.